# Feature extraction ideas for short phrases

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language

I have a dataset of around 1 million short phrases (mostly 2-3 words) and they are labelled as either appropriate or inappropriate.

E.g. phrases include "cute kittens", "pasta recipes", and "how to dye hair".

Currently, I'm using 3 features:

- bag of words
- 2-gram
- character 3-gram
- character 4-gram
- bag of soundexes

I don't have a word embedding that works well with this dataset. Are there more features I could add?